# Dynamic HTML content pages like Dropbox and Soundcloud

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dynamic

Check out the source code of [Dropbox's main page](https://www.dropbox.com/) or any [Soundcloud page](https://soundcloud.com/madsonik/criminal-madsonik-remix). You can see they've got a lot of Scripts going on, and little pure HTML content (`article`, `main`, `p`, `div`). I've been searching and it seems that way of generating pages is called **dynamic content/HTML** (correct me if wrong).

So, the function I think it has is to be able to edit multiple external separate files in Javascript (if that's the language it uses since they're scripts) so that the HTML documentes where they're linked to are generated dynamically.

Also, other possible function would be to have one external document, which let's say it's a navigation bar, and so you place it in multiple pages, and when you have to update, you just edit the external document and not each page (hooray!).

### Questions:

1. Is it actually named *Dynamic content*?
2. What languages does it requires besides HTML, CSS, and JS? Like PHP or ASP (supposing if any is necesary at all).
3. Does creating pages in that way affects negatively/positively your website positioning in Google? Since **I think** when Googlebot reaches the page all it see are scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two subtly different definitions of the word *dynamic*, which may be confusing your search for information about this. I'll answer your questions separately for each.

### Dynamic as in "generated from content held in a database"

For example, on this page your reputation score was fetched from Stack Overflow's database and injected into the HTML.

1. Yes, this would be referred to as *dynamic content*. In contrast to *static content*, which would just be fixed files, dynamic content would be built up from its parts for each user who requests it.
2. Your second set of languages (PHP, etc.) are what read from the database and spit out the corresponding HTML.
3. Google's bot is smart: it can render pages and will see similar content to what you get in a browser. So generating pages dynamically instead of statically won't count against the site for SEO; dynamically generating lots of pages that are *very similar* might count against it though.

### Dynamic as in "page content that updates without you having to refresh the whole page"

For example, as you wrote your question Stack Overflow tried to find similar questions and show them to you in case it had already been asked. JavaScript was sending a request to their server and updating part of the page in response.

1. This would also be referred to as dynamic content. The key difference is that it's JavaScript in the page that's making further calls to the server to fetch more content, which is what you're seeing on the minimalist sites you mention. This used to be called dynamic HTML (DHTML); more modern references are more likely to discuss it in terms of AJAX or "single page website".
2. Typically you'd have PHP or similar running on the web server, responding to the requests for content.
3. Again, Google's bot is smart enough to cope with this. That won't necessarily be the case for all search engines though.

Comment: As for the first answer, how could I do that (don't to make full/long answer)? So far I can also do that with JavaScript (or jQuery) using `.innerHTML = ""`. Do you know other ways? Finally, do you have any ideas which methods Dropbox/SoundCloud uses?

Comment: @alej27 This looks like a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application